# How can I add my desired editor to the "update-alternatives" interactive menu?

Tags: alternative, update-alternatives

Ive just installed ubuntu 16.04.2 32 bit on a digital ocean server.

Digital ocean has  tweaked the ubuntu install a bit, for example they have installed full vim as part of the block image they use in their VPS's.
I now want to use this - pre-installed - vim as my default editor. so I run

```
sudo update-alternatives --config editor
```

which gives this menu

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config editor
There are 4 choices for the alternative editor (providing /usr/bin/editor).

  Selection    Path                Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /bin/nano            40        auto mode
  1            /bin/ed             -100       manual mode
  2            /bin/nano            40        manual mode
  3            /usr/bin/vim.basic   30        manual mode
  4            /usr/bin/vim.tiny    10        manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

**note: vim is not there as an option**

Im thinking digital ocean has not added the vim install to the update-alternatives system?
What is the recommended way to get the `/user/bin/vim` program added to this menu?
I guess I could overwrite the `/usr/bin/editor` symlink that the alternatives system adds or maybe add a symlink in `/etc/alternatives` pointing to `/usr/bin/vim` ? but I would like to try the "official" way before I do my "hack" on top of the digital ocean hack.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is not modified, but the standard Ubuntu behaviour up to Zesty. If you do a `ls -l` on `vim` (`/usr/bin/vim`), you see that it is a link to `/etc/alternatives/vim`, which in turn links to `/usr/bin/vim.basic`.

Execution of `vim --version` or `vim.basic --version` also reveals that they are in fact the same full, "giant" `vim` version 8.0 without GUI.

To answer your question: Menu choice of `vim.basic` gives you the desired full `vim` version. It is just that the name is misleading.

Answer (score 15):

First set your editor to the right path:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/editor editor /usr/local/bin/vim 1 && \
sudo update-alternatives --set editor /usr/local/bin/vim
```

Then aliases:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/vi vi /usr/local/bin/vim 1 && \
sudo update-alternatives --set vi /usr/local/bin/vim
```

Don't forget the 1 near the end of the first line of both code blocks above.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer: it answers the question on how to add a custom editor to the alternatives

Answer (score 7):

You can add any new editor and set it as default by using a single command. In this example you would be adding [micro editor](https://micro-editor.github.io/), located in `/usr/bin/micro` as an [update alternative](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man1/update-alternatives.1.html) editor with a priority of `100`. The command is:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/editor editor /usr/bin/micro 100
```

The system will use the editor with the highest priority by default if there isn't any previous selection. So, with this single command, you can add a new editor, and use it as the default editor. All you need is that the priority is larger than any of the previous you have in your update-alternatives list.

Comment: If micro was installed with [brew](https://brew.sh/) the path would be `/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/micro`